# Regular Expression to accept 'System Admin' and 'Systems Admin' strings in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, sql-server-2008

I need to keep track of strings that are equal to 'System Admin' and 'Systems Admin'

I used `LIKE` expression with square brackets but that should contains at least one character.

```
LIKE 'System[] Admin'
```

How do I track strings that are equal to 'System Admin' and 'Systems Admin'

Comment: Unfortunately, the T-SQL `Like` operator is quite limited. It only has one concept that accommodates a variable number of characters - `%` - and you have no control over how many characters that actually matches. Everything else you specify deals with single characters (either an exact character, an underscore to match any character, or a range expressions that describes a subset of acceptable characters to match a single character)

Comment: The most straight forward option I see is to replace the `LIKE` with something like `IN ('System Admin', 'Systems Admin')`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this,

```
DECLARE @sql TABLE (col1 VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @sql
VALUES ('Systems Admin')
    ,('System Admin')
    ,('SystemA Admin')
    ,('Sys Admin')

SELECT *
FROM @sql
WHERE col1 LIKE 'System_ Admin'
    OR col1 LIKE 'System Admin'
```